# Swift string interpolation with formatter

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, I can use string interpolation with a formatter parameter. It works in several places, for example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    static let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .long
        return formatter
    }()

    let currentDate = Date()
    @State var userInput = ""
    @State var selection = ""

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text("This is a date: \(currentDate, formatter: Self.dateFormatter)")
            Picker("This is also a date: \(currentDate, formatter: Self.dateFormatter)",
                   selection: self.$selection) {
                Text("Dummy")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way of string interpolation seems to be defined in SwiftUI, because if I "jump to definition" in Xcode, the following lines show up:

```
public mutating func appendInterpolation<Subject>(_ subject: Subject, formatter: Formatter? = nil) where Subject : ReferenceConvertible

public mutating func appendInterpolation<Subject>(_ subject: Subject, formatter: Formatter? = nil) where Subject : NSObject
```

When I try and use this form of string interpolation in a Playground, it fails with an error:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    return formatter
}()
let date = Date()

print("Current date: \(date, formatter: dateFormatter)")
```

The above playground fails with the following error:

```
error: StringInterpolationWithFormatter.playground:12:41: error: extra argument 'formatter' in call
print("Current date: \(date, formatter: dateFormatter)")
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to use the `formatter:` argument in a string interpolation with `Text`, because the [`Text` initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:tablename:bundle:comment:)) accepts a `LocalizedStringKey`, rather than a `String`.

[`LocalizedStringKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/localizedstringkey) has defined some special string interpolation features with the [`appendInterpolation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/localizedstringkey/stringinterpolation/appendinterpolation(_:formatter:)-9vdw4) overloads (in `LocalizedStringKey.StringInterpolation`) you showed, which is why you can use the `formatter:` argument with it.

However, in the print statement, you are simply printing a string, and a string uses [`DefaultStringInterpolation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/defaultstringinterpolation), which does not have a `appendInterpolation` overload that accepts a `formatter:` argument.

Simply create an extension of `DefaultStringInterpolation` to add this new string interpolation if you want:

```
extension DefaultStringInterpolation {
    // signature copied from LocalizedStringKey.StringInterpolation
    mutating func appendInterpolation<Subject>(_ subject: Subject, formatter: Formatter) {
        appendInterpolation(formatter.string(for: subject)!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You first need to create your own StringInterpolation for string. Like this

```
extension String.StringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation(_ date: Date, formatter: DateFormatter) {
        appendLiteral(formatter.string(from: date))
    }
}
```

And now you can use

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    return formatter
}()
let date = Date()

print("Current date: \(date, formatter: dateFormatter)")
```

You can read more about string interpolation [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/178/super-powered-string-interpolation-in-swift-5-0)